# Adding line breaks in between each error in validation_errors()

Tags: php, codeigniter

How would I go about displaying the errors like this:

error1:

error2:

error3:

when I `echo validation_errors()` it just returns it line after line:

error1:
error2:
error3:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [2nd parameter](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#validation_errors) to add a suffix :

```
echo validation_errors('', '<br>');
```

Or using prefix/suffix :

```
echo validation_errors('<p>', '</p>');
```